# Clearing object after method call

Tags: php, class

How can I clear an object after calling a specified method?

I have a class `DB` and would like to clear all properties after calling `mysqli->query()`.

```
class DB
{
    private $mysqli = 'This is an instantiated MySQLi object';
    private $sql    = 'This variable is filled with an SQL query';

    public function query()
    {
        $tmp = $this->mysqli->query($this->sql); // Start MySQLi query to MySQLi server

        $this->clearObject(NULL); // clear all properties of this object

        var_dump($tmp); // until here $tmp is still declared as mysqli_result

        return $tmp; // return the temporary variable $tmp. $tmp is NULL now.
    }
}

$DB = new DB;
$DB->query();
```

I already have the method `clearObject(NULL)` that works fine but when I try to run the code I get the error message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

though `$tmp` is still defined as `object(mysqli_result)` after call `$this->clearObject(NULL)`.

It seems that `return $tmp` tries to "redeclare" `$tmp` before returning it - is this right? How could I fix this issue?

PS: `clearObject(NULL` sets all property values to `NULL`, that's why the error message contains `null`.
PPS: I DO NOT want to destroy (`unset()`) the object `DB`!

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I just prevent `$mysqli` from being cleared. `$sql` (that actually MUST be cleared after `mysqli->query()` is cleared and so the error message is

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query

Comment: Escape `'` for this word `That's` in this line: `private $mysqli = 'That\'s an instantiated MySQLi object';`

Comment: I just say to you escape in your code, not here... this could be the cause of your problem. could you please confirm if this was your problem? I post this answer bellow. If not, I'll remove it. =)

Comment: @CBroe : Because I want to use a fresh one after calling `query()`. But the actual problem is not the `$mysqli` than rather the `$sql` property.

Comment: did your try to put the clearObject function to __destruct()  block?

Comment: @Cherry: No because I don't want to destroy the object. I just want to clear it. This is a "global object" within in my system so I can't destroy it.